# The way to programatically distinguish between system process and the process launched by the user(for example,game process)

Tags: ios, process

How to programatically  distinguish between system process and the process launched by the user(for example,game process)?

Comment: Just want to display a process list which only contains processes launched by user.

Answer (score 0):

I have to solve a similar problem and am getting the process list in basically the same way as here: [Can I use `sysctl` to retrieve a process list with the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729245/can-i-use-sysctl-to-retrieve-a-process-list-with-the-user).  I am getting the current user ID by finding the process that matches my current app name, and then throwing out all the processes that have a different user ID.  That seems to get rid of about 1/2 of the system processes.

Throwing out any process with a pid less than 100 seems to get rid of nearly all the other system processes, and what I'm left with looks pretty good.  There are still a few system processes left, and I think I'm going to just ignore them by name.  (Though I'm not sure if they are only there because I'm debugging on my phone.)